# What am I doing wrong? (Coding Syntax Error)

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, velo

[image]

Why do I get red lines on `fieldName` and `order`? I’m following the API reference here:

https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-pricing-plans-backend/orders/listcurrentmemberorders

Here's a sample from the example in the reference:

```
/* Sample filters object: 
 * {
 *   orderStatuses: ['PAUSED', 'CANCELED']
 * }
 */

/* Sample sorting object: 
 * {
 *   fieldName: ['createdDate'], 
 *   order: ['ASC']
 * }
 */

/* Sample paging object: 
 * {
 *   limit: 3,
 *   skip: 1
 * }
 */
```

The red line error says: `Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'`

I feel like I’m doing what the linked reference says, and have tried various setups from exploring the reference.

(EDIT: And the next thing to look into would be why `orders` on `listedOrders.orders` throws the error: `Property 'orders' does not exist on type 'Order[]'.` )

Is the answer that the API reference is outdated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the comment in the code example is wrong.
In the documentation, not the code example, it says
[image]

You see `fieldName` and `order` are `string`, not `Array<String>`.
Also, `fieldName`'s supported values include `_createdDate` but not `createdDate`.

Try changing the parameter to

```
{ fieldName: '_createdDate', order: 'ASC' }
```

Comment: This resolved my issue. Thanks!

Do you have any thoughts on the second part (the EDIT) of my post: Why `orders` on `listedOrders.orders` throws the error: Property `'orders' does not exist on type 'Order[]'.` ?

Comment: @JohnOle Likewise, in the document, there is no member named `orders` in the `Returns`'s member. Also, `listedOrders` is already an array. Try using `listedOrders[0]`.

Comment: Ah. I guess their example is quite outdated. Alright, thanks!

Comment: Removing `orders` and just having `listedOrders[0]` worked. No red lines. I've tried running this, though, but I don't see any result, also not on the live site. I guess I should console.log something?

Comment: @JohnOle The *back end* (function) itself by definition does not show anything to the user on the live site. You should implement/modify the *front end* (UI/UX) that uses the back end code. Or at least, call the function somewhere and print the result to the console.

Answer (score 0):

The default value is what you are looking for. According to the documentation so you can simply send the sorting as null or write "_createdDate" instead of
"createdDate":
[image]

also, you can use IDE like Visual Studio code and hover to get more details on what's wrong.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yup, that's the solution. Thanks :)

Do you have any thoughts on the second part (the EDIT) of my post?

Why `orders` on `listedOrders.orders` throws the error: Property `'orders' does not exist on type 'Order[]'.` ?